# How to perform gui operation in doInBackground method?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

My application reads a user selected file which contains addresses and then displays on mapview when done geocoding. To avoid hanging app the importing and geocoding is done in AsyncTask.

```
public class LoadOverlayAsync extends AsyncTask<Uri, Integer, StopsOverlay> {

    Context context;
    MapView mapView;
    Drawable drawable;

    public LoadOverlayAsync(Context con, MapView mv, Drawable dw)
    {
        context = con;
        mapView = mv;
        drawable = dw;
    }

    protected StopsOverlay doInBackground(Uri... uris)
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        StopsOverlay stopsOverlay = new StopsOverlay(drawable, context);
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(context, Locale.US);

        try
        {   
            File file = new File(new URI(uris[0].toString()));

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                StopOverlay stopOverlay = null;
                String[] tempLine = line.split("~");
                List<Address> results = geo.getFromLocationName(tempLine[4] + " " + tempLine[5] + " " + tempLine[7] + " " + tempLine[8], 10);

                if (results.size() > 0)
                {
                    Toast progressToast = Toast.makeText(context, "More than one yo", 1000);
                    progressToast.show();
                }
                else if (results.size() == 1)
                {
                    Address addr = results.get(0);
                    GeoPoint mPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(addr.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int)(addr.getLongitude() * 1E6));
                    stopOverlay = new StopOverlay(mPoint, tempLine);
                }

                if (stopOverlay != null)
                {
                    stopsOverlay.addOverlay(stopOverlay);
                }
                //List<Address> results = geo.getFromLocationName(locationName, maxResults)

            }

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            showErrorToast(e.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            showErrorToast(e.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            showErrorToast(e.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stopsOverlay;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
    {
        Toast progressToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Loaded " + progress.toString(), 1000);
        progressToast.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(StopsOverlay so)
    {
        //mapView.getOverlays().add(so);
        Toast progressToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Done geocoding", 1000);
        progressToast.show();
    }

    protected void showErrorToast(String msg)
    {
        Toast Newtoast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, 10000);
        Newtoast.show();
    }
}
```

But if geocode fails, I want a dialog popup to let user edit the address. That would require calling on gui method while in doInBackground. What would be a good workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to handle it in your onPostExecute method.  Perhaps design it so a null argument to onPostExecute indicates that it failed, so in that case pop up the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the Result type of StopsOverlay, then what you can do is set some member fields in doInBackground, then check those in onPostExecute and show your error UI at that point.

Note that this is safe and recommended per the [AsyncTask docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> AsyncTask guarantees that all callback calls are synchronized in such a way that the following operations are safe without explicit synchronizations.
>
> Set member fields in doInBackground(Params...), and refer to them in onProgressUpdate(Progress...) and onPostExecute(Result).

For example, you could declare a field:

```
private boolean mTooManyResults = false;
```

Then change it so that in `doInBackground`, you have code like:

```
if (results.size() > 0)
{
    mTooManyResults = true;
}
```

Then in `onPostExecute`:

```
if (mTooManyResults)
{
    // notify user about error
    Toast progressToast = Toast.makeText(context, "More than one yo", 1000);
    progressToast.show();
} else
{
    // notify user about success
    Toast progressToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Done geocoding", 1000);
    progressToast.show();
}
```

Comment: One more thing, I need to pass the line data (the one that can't be decoded) String[] tempLine = line.split("~"); to method where dialog will be called. I am thinking about making an array with failed geocodings. Then list thru them in onPostExecute to let user edit it.

Comment: You can set that to a member field as well, perhaps mGeocodingOutputLines in doInBackground and then display it onPostExecute.  I think that would be fine.